# onmouseout not working, however onmouseover is

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onmouseover, onmouseout

Apologies if you're seeing this post twice, I felt like I could've explained things a lot better.

Basically, I'm creating a page where I have a bunch of elements, and when the mouse hovers over it, a "status" box will overlay on top of it, and when the mouse leaves, it will disappear again. Through Django, I'm passing in a python dictionary with the identifier code and specs of each item, the specs itself is another dictionary, with specific fields like "image url", "status"...etc.

Then I'm running a for loop for every object in the dictionary, to render a separate HTML element for each one of them. When the page first loads, a bunch of images appear, then when the user hovers over one, the corresponding "status"div--also created by the for loop-- should show up. Each of the status div also has a unique id, that is the identifier code of the object (the key of the dict that I passed).

I'm using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` on the images to create the show-on-hover, and each one of them goes to a separate Javascript function that either shows or hides the overlay div. Inside a hidden h1, I'm storing the identifier code for this particular object. The function for show and hide is then getting the innerHTML of that h1 (which is the code), finding the status div with an id of that code, and showing/hiding that div.

I have no problem getting the div to show up when the mouse moves over the image. However, it seems as the `onmouseout` part of it doesn't work, as when my mouse leaves the image, nothing changes and the overlay div is still there. I believe that it is an issue with the `onmouseout`, not the function, since the function just isn't running (I put a console.log to test, and nothing is showing up in the console).

**HTML code**

```
{% for listing, specs in listings.items %}
      <div class="status" id="{{ listing }}">
      </div>
      <div class="list-item" onmouseover="showstatus(this)" onmouseout="normalize(this)">
           <h1 class="hidden">{{listing}}</h1>
           <img src="{{specs.pic}}" class="item-thumbnail">
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**javascript**

```
function showstatus(object) {
    var code = object.querySelector('h1').innerHTML
    document.querySelector(`#${code}`).style.display="block";
}

function normalize(object) {
    var code = object.querySelector('h1').innerHTML
    document.querySelector(`#${code}`).style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `onmouseleave` ? And `onmouseover` should be `onmouseenter` i guess.

Comment: @patriktorkildsen I tried that, and it still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your result i guess its because the overlay covers the elements and prevents the mouseleave from firing.

Try this

```html
{% for listing, specs in listings.items %}
<div class="status" id="{{ listing }}"  onmouseleave="normalize(this)">
</div>
<div class="list-item" onmouseenter="showstatus(this)">
       <h1 class="hidden">{{listing}}</h1>
       <img src="{{specs.pic}}" class="item-thumbnail">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

```js
function showstatus(object) {
var code = object.querySelector('h1').innerHTML
document.querySelector(`#${code}`).style.display="block";
}

function normalize(object) {
object.style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: The overlay does cover the elements, so I changed the overlay to have the mouseleave, but it still isn't working. Could it be because the overlay is absolutely positioned maybe?